# Listening webhook for discord bot's top.gg page using heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

I have my bot hosted on heroku and I have a top.gg page for the bot. Top.gg uses webhooks to send post requests regarding bot votes but I can not figure out how to receive these posts using heroku.

The code for the node js is this:

```
const webhook = new Topgg.Webhook("my auth code");

app.post("/dblwebhook", webhook.middleware(), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.vote.user);
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

And the top.gg page looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiSxS.png

How can I connect them together on heroku?
Any help at all on the matter would be appreciated because I have been trying for 17h straight

Answer (score 0):

It sends a Post request to the URL that's provided.

here's a [example](https://github.com/telkenes/dbl-discord-webhook/tree/javascript) one github

You can refer that for help.